# Given a String 'a' - Check for occurrences of String 'b' in 'a' and replace those occurrences with String 'c'

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have working code that does the check for pattern of String 'b' in 'a' and replaces those with String 'c'. It makes use of String.split() and sweeps thru the String 'a' multiple times, finds indices to do the replacement and uses a StringBuilder to avoid superfluous copying of String 'a'. So it runs in linear time O(n).

Now, the problem is that if there are overlapping pattern matches, I still get a positive match. For example in case of String a = 'ababa' --> I get two matches for String b = 'aba'. How to resolve this by replacing only the first full occurrence and not identifying the remaining characters 'ba' as a match. I expect a result of a = 'cba' if String c = 'c'.

Here is the code I have.

```
public static String replaceSubstringWithPattern () {
    String a = "abab";
    String b = "aba";
    String c = "c";

    //Special Cases --> if a or b are empty no need to substitute
    if (a.isEmpty() || b.isEmpty()) return a;

    StringBuilder aTemp = new StringBuilder();
    String[] aArray = a.split(b);  // <-- 
    System.out.println("aArray = " + aArray.length);

    //Special Cases --> no splits because string a is exclusive repetition of string b
    if (aArray.length == 0) {
        for (int x = 0; x < a.length()/b.length(); x++) {
            aTemp.append(c);
        }
        return aTemp.toString();
    }

    aTemp.append(aArray[0]);    //firstElement

    for (int i=1; i<aArray.length; i++) {
        aTemp.append(c);
        aTemp.append(aArray[i]);
    }

    return aTemp.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you not just do `a.replaceFirst(b, c);`?

Comment: `result = a.replace(b, c);`?

Comment: If this is a homework assignment please note it so that we can give better guidance without giving a direct answer, otherwise the answer given is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
String a="ababa";
String b="aba";
String c="c";

System.out.println("result= " + a.replaceFirst(b,c));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
result= cba
```